# Different toolbar config for multiple CKEditor instances on same page?

Tags: ckeditor

Say I have 3 CKeditor instances on the same page.

- For instances #1 and #2, I want to use toolbar config A.
- For instance #3, I want to use toolbar config B.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

```
var toolbar_config_A = [
    // here you put toolbar config A
];
var toolbar_config_B = [
    // here you put toolbar config B
];
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    toolbar: toolbar_config_A
});
CKEDITOR.replace('editor2', {
    toolbar: toolbar_config_A
});
CKEDITOR.replace('editor3', {
    toolbar: toolbar_config_B
});
```